# How to translate this sort algorithm to mips assembly

Tags: algorithm, assembly, mips, mips32

My homework for my Computer Architecture was to write a program in MIPS assembly that can sort a 2D array in ascending order. I wrote a bubblesort algo in Java that can do this; however, I still am very new to MIPS and have no idea how to use the same logic in MIPS syntax.

Specifically, how might I construct the while-for loops in MIPS? I know how the if and method calls translate (jal/j/jr and bgt/blt/slt) but I'm having trouble understanding how to structure my for-loops

```
public class D2ArraySort {

    public static int[][] switchValsEnd(int[][] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp;
        temp = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[i + 1][0];
        a[i + 1][0] = temp;
        return a;
    }

    public static int[][] switchVals(int[][] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp;
        temp = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[i][j + 1];
        a[i][j + 1] = temp;
        return a;
    }

    public static int[][] sort(int[][] a) {
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                    if (j == a[i].length - 1 && i != a.length - 1) {
                        if (a[i][j] < a[i + 1][0]) {
                            a = switchValsEnd(a, i, j);
                            i = 0;
                            j = -1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (j == a[i].length - 1) {
                            return a;
                        }
                        if (a[i][j] < a[i][j + 1]) {
                            a = switchVals(a, i, j);
                            i = 0;
                            j = -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { // don't need main other than to call j sort
        int[][] input_data = { // global input_data
                {2, 0, -7, -1, 3, 8, -4, 10},
                {-9, -16, 15, 13, 1, 4, -3, 14},
                {-8, -10, -15, 6, -13, -5, 9, 12},
                {-11, -14, -6, 11, 5, 7, -2, -12},
        };
        int[][] output_data = sort(input_data); // jal sort
        for (int i = 0; i < output_data.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("( ");
            for (int j = 0; j < output_data[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(output_data[i][j] + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println(")");
        }
    }    
}
```

Expected output:
( 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, )
( 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, )`enter code here`
( -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, )
( -9, -10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16, )

MIPS Assembly so far (I have no idea where to start with the while-for loops):
Also ignore my incomplete main method lol

```
#
#  Author: Joshua Baroni
#  Date: October 16, 2019
#  Description: Sorting 2D array in descending order
#
.text
.align 4

main:


sort:

    la $t4, vals #t0 is number up to outer loop
    la $t1, vals #t1 is number comparing to inner loop
    addi $t1,$t1,4
    la $t8,vals
    add $t8,$t0,$t8
    la $t9,vals
    add $t9,$t0,$t9
    addi $t9,$t9,-4
    loops: lw $t2,($t4) #get number 1 outer loop
    lw $t3,($t1) #get number 2 inner loop
    bgt $t2,$t3, next #don't need to swap
    sw $t3,($t4) #swap
    sw $t2,($t1)
    next: addi $t1,$t1,4
    bgt $t1,$t8,loops #inner loop done?
    addi $t4,$t4,4 #yes-increment outer loop
    move $t1,$t4
    addi $t1,$t1,4
    bgt $t4,$t9,loops #outer loop done?


.data
.align 4
Input_data:
    .word 2, 0, -7, -1, 3, 8, -4, 10
    .word -9, -16, 15, 13, 1, 4, -3, 14
    .word -8, -10, -15, 6, -13, -5, 9, 12
    .word -11, -14, -6, 11, 5, 7, -2, -12
Output_data:
    .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: The 2D array looks like it's laid out sequentially in memory. So you could treat it as a one-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.data
.align 4
Input_data:

    .word 2, 0, -7, -1, 3, 8, -4, 10
    .word -9, -16, 15, 13, 1, 4, -3, 14
    .word -8, -10, -15, 6, -13, -5, 9, 12
    .word -11, -14, -6, 11, 5, 7, -2, -12

Output_data:
        .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

    comma: .asciiz ", "

    parenthesis_open: .asciiz "("

    parenthesis_close: .asciiz ")"

    newline: .asciiz "\n"

    .text
    .globl main
    main:


        jal sort     # call sort function

        li $t0,0       # j=0
        li $t2,0       # i=0

        # int[][] output_data = sort(input_data);

        copy_array_i:       # loop for int i ....

            addiu  $t2,$t2,32   # i = i+1 (+32 in reality , each line has 8 elements * 4 bytes each one )

            copy_array_j:       # loop for int j ..

            lw $t1,Input_data($t0)     # $t1 = a[i][j]
            sw $t1,Output_data($t0)    # store the element to Output_data at same index


        addiu $t0,$t0,4            # index = index +1 (+4 in reality because each number weights 4 bytes)

        bne $t0,$t2,copy_array_j    # if index != output_data[i].length -1 , jump to for (int j...)


        bne $t2,128,copy_array_i    # if i != 128 (4 bytes *8 elements * 4 lines )


        li $s1,0
        li $s2,0

        print_out:
            addiu $s2,$s2,32
            la $a0, parenthesis_open  #load address into $a0
            li $v0, 4      #call to print string
        syscall

        inner_loop:
        lw $s0,Output_data($s1)  # $s0 = Output_data[i][j]

        li $v0, 1       #print the Output_data element
        move $a0, $s0
        syscall 
        addiu $s1,$s1,4

            la $a0, comma  #load address into $a0
            li $v0, 4      #call to print comma
        syscall
        bne $s1,$s2,inner_loop  

            la $a0, parenthesis_close  #load address into $a0
            li $v0, 4      #call to print parenthesis closed
        syscall

        la $a0, newline  #load address into $a0
            li $v0, 4      #call to print newline
        syscall

        #addiu $s3,$s3,32

        bne $s2,128,print_out

    li $v0, 10 # system call for exit
    syscall


    sort:
    addi $sp,$sp,-4
    sw $ra,0($sp)


        li $s0,128            # a.length  8*4*4
        li $s5,96           # a.length -1 8*4*3
        li $s1,32            # a[i].length  8*4 bytes
        li $s2,28            # a[i].length -1  7*4 bytes
        li $s3,0             # i
        li $s4,0             # j

    while:

        li $s3,0  # i = 0

        for_i:

            li $s4,0   # j =0
            for_j:

                seq  $t0,$s4,$s2 # if j == a[i].length -1 => $t0 =1 else $t0=0
                sne  $t1,$s3,$s5 # if i != a.length -1  => $t1=1 else $t1=0
                and  $t2,$t0,$t1  # logical and between $t0 and $t1 , storing the result into $t2
                bne  $t2,1,else   # if !(j == a[i].length - 1 && i != a.length - 1)  go to else label


                li $t0,0           # $t0 =0
                li $t1,0           # $t1=0
                addu $t0,$s3,$s4   # $t0 = i + j

                lw $t2,Input_data($t0)  # to get  a[i][j] into $t2


                addiu $t1,$s3,32    # $t1 = i+1  (+1 => +32 bytes)

                lw $t3,Input_data($t1)   # to get a[i+1][0]


                bge $t2,$t3, inc_i_or_j  # if a[i][j] >= a[i+1][0] go to inc_i_or_j label

                move $a0,$s3            # first parameter => i
                move $a1,$s4            # second parameter => j
                jal switchValsEnd       # call switchValsEnd function

                li $3,0                 #  i=0

                li $s4,0                # j=0

                j for_j                # go to for int j  ....

                inc_i_or_j:            #inc_i_or_j label

                beq $s3,$s5,while       # if i == a.length -1 => go to while label

                addiu $s3,$s3,32        # else  i=i+1
                j for_i                 # jump to for_i label

            else:

            bne $s4,$s2,second_if           # if j!= a[i].length -1  go to second if 


            lw $ra,0($sp)                    # restore return address stored into stack
            addiu $sp,$sp,4                  # free stack
            jr $ra              # jump to caller (main)


            second_if:

            li $t0,0
            li $t3,0
            addu $t0,$s3,$s4                # $t0 = i+j


            lw $t4,Input_data($t0)  # a[i][j]

            addu $t3,$s3,$s4                # $t0 = i+j
            addiu $t3,$t3,4                 # $t3 = i+ (j+1)

            lw $t5,Input_data($t3)   #  a[i][j + 1]

            bge $t4,$t5,inc_j         # if a[i][j] >= a[i][j+1] go to inc_j label               

            move $a0,$s3             # first parameter i
            move $a1,$s4             # second parameter j
            jal switchVals           # call switchVals function


            li $s3,0                # i=0
            li $s4,0                # j=0

            j for_j                 # jump to for int j ...

            inc_j:                   # inc_j label
                addiu $s4,$s4,4  # j = j+1 (+4 because each number = 4 bytes )
                j for_j          # jump to for (int j ...)


switchValsEnd:
    addi $sp,$sp,-4         #allocate space in stack (4 bytes)
    sw $ra,0($sp)           # store return address 

    li $t2,0        

    addu $t2,$a0,$a1         # $t2 =i + j

    lw $t4,Input_data($t2)   # temp= a[i][j]

    li $t1,0

    addu  $t1,$t1,$a0         # $t1 = i
    addiu $t1,$t1,32          # $t1 = i+1 (+32)


    lw $t5,Input_data($t1)  # a[i+1][0]

    sw $t5,Input_data($t2)  #     a[i][j] = a[i + 1][0];


    sw $t4,Input_data($t1)   # a[i+1][0] = temp

    lw $ra,0($sp)            # restore $ra (return address ) from stack 
    addi $sp,$sp,4            # free stack's element 
    jr $ra                   # return to caller ( sort function )

switchVals:
    addi $sp,$sp,-4
    sw $ra,0($sp)

    # $a0 = i
    # $a1 = j
    li $t1,0
    li $t7,0

    addu $t1,$a0,$a1         # $t1 = i+j


    lw $t3,Input_data($t1)   # temp  = a[i][j]

    addu $t5,$a0,$a1         # $t5 = i + j
    addiu $t5,$t5,4          # $t5 = i + (j+1)

    lw $t8,Input_data($t5)        # a[i] [j+1]

    sw $t8,Input_data($t1)  #     a[i][j] = a[i][j+1];


    sw $t3,Input_data($t5)   #   a[i][j] = a[i][j + 1];

    lw $ra,0($sp)            # restore $ra (return address ) from stack 
    addi $sp,$sp,4            # free stack's element 
    jr $ra                   # return to caller ( sort function )
```

Comment: Nice comments on the individual instructions. When you come across this code 31 months from now, how long will it take you to figure out the sorting algorithm?

Comment: @greybeard This algorithm is long and a bit difficult to understand but, the translation line by line from java code to mips improves its comprehension (in my opinion)

Have you an alternative of this algorithm, to able to compare with my solution ?